# Catch event from component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In VueJS 2 I'm using a component (vuejs-datepicker) and I'm trying to catch a specific event emitted by the component :

Looking trought the source code, the component use at some point :

```
this.$emit('cleared')
```

I would like to catch this information and trigger an action based on it directly on the parent.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: I'm not sure to which part of the documentation I have to refer, considering that I cannot modify the component source code

Comment: I assume there is a datepicker component, so it would be `<datepicker @cleared='myHandler'></datepicker>`